Creating a vector of in which Mardia's b1p can be saved
i want to create a vector that have 'q0' rows and 1 column with N repetitions.
My minimum working example is:
library(Matrix)
library(psych)
library(MASS) 
set.seed(10)
N0 <- 2
n0 <- 5
p0 <- 2
q0 <- 4
n  <- n0*q0
m2 <- matrix(c(0,0),p0,1)
s2 <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1),p0,p0)
Dat <- array(dim=c(n0, length(m2),  q0, N0))
mardia_ary <- array(dim=c(q0,1, N0),data=NA) 
for (i in 1:N0) {
  for (j in 1:q0) {
    Dat[,,j,i] <- mvrnorm(n = n0, m2, s2)
     mardia_ary[,j,i] <- mardia(Dat[,,j,i], plot = FALSE)$b1p
  }
}
Dat
mardia_ary


I want to store mardia's b1p in that vector.
In this case the output should be 2 repetitions having 4 rows and 1 column with mardia's b1p stored in it.
When i tried the mentioned code, it gives me a vector of q0 rows and 1 column. I'm resulted in
, , 1
     [,1]
[1,] 0.7766085
[2,] 0.7766085
[3,] 0.7766085
[4,] 0.7766085
, , 2
  [,1]
[1,] NA
[2,] NA
[3,] NA
[4,] NA


But what i'm expecting is:
, , 1
     [,1]
[1,] 0.77660
[2,] 1.16840
[3,] 0.16811
[4,] 1.11721
, , 2
  [,1]
[1,] 0.16
[2,] 0.61
[3,] 0.28
[4,] 0.59


You don't get Error subscript out of bounds, which seems similar to problems encountered in previous approach/question?

No, i didn't get that error. The main difference in this and the previous question is i'm trying to convert mardia's b1p into an array not in a list.
